# Brent Crude Data

Tags: options, volatility, data

I am trying to locate historical volatility data (5+ years) for Brent Crude?  Does anyone know where I might be able to source such data?

Comment: Questions about where to find data are considered off-topic for quant.se  Please see the FAQ:  http://quant.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this site can help http://www.eia.doe.gov/. It is a little confusing to navigate, but the prices are here:

http://tonto.eia.doe.gov/dnav/pet/pet_pri_spt_s1_d.htm

Comment: Thank you.  This is useful spot pricing.  I am also looking for volatilites (IV).